# MVC3 - Is it legal to define helper methods inside razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting Error:

`CS1513: } expected`

I don't see any missing brackets.  In my experience, the razor parser sometimes gets tripped on on determining HTML vs C# so I take these errors with a grain of salt.

I made a few modifications, namely I added a helper method.  Is it legal to define a method implementation in the View via razor?  E.G.

```
@{
                protected string MyHelper(int ItemNumber, int RowNumber, int ColumnNumber)
                {
                    string irc = "";
                    irc += "i" + ItemNumber;
                    irc += "r" + RowNumber;
                    irc += "c" + ColumnNumber;
                    return irc;
                }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Razor actually has a built-in helper construct:

```
@helper greet(string s) {
    <span>Hi there, @s!</span>
}
```

Comment: +1 - This is useful information.  I converted the method above to use the helper keyword.  Unfortunately, I still have the same error therefore I can't choose this as an answer just yet.  This also does not directly answer the question as to whether my original syntax is legal.

Comment: It's not legal because the `@{...}` construct is at the method level, not the class level. You could define an `Action<...>` if you wanted, but that's all.

Comment: As to why it's not working, not sure, a straightforward `@:i@ItemNumber@:r@RowNumber@:c@ColumnNumber` inside the helper should do it. Make sure you don't add a return value.

Comment: @Blindy: the reason is that the text you put in the razor file "goes" into a method in a code generated class. The @{} part will be "copy/pasted" as code, the rest has to be embedded into some kind of Write("") calls. This generated class gets finally compiled, and if you do something wrong you can see the compilation error that relates to this code generated file. So you get the same C# compiler error as if you would try to write a method declaration inside another method body (because this is what happens).

Comment: Did I somehow imply I wasn't aware of that?